# Issue when using Entity Framework and PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I'm currently experiencing issues when using Entity Framework 6 and PostgreSQL, when I create a table that doesn't have any relationships it works just fine, but when I do one with one relationship I get an error like the following:

> A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a
>   store-generated column. Column: 'person_type_id'.

I double checked my tables and everything seems to be configured correctly, check for instance this two **Person** and **Person Type**:

￼[image: Person and Person Type Tables]

As you can see there, in Person, the column person_type_id acts as foreign key to the Person Type table, and person_id is the primary key.

This is the code I'm trying to implement:

```
//Creating db Context
postgresEntities db = new postgresEntities();

//Creation of Person new instance
person nPer = new person();

//Asigning person_type with ID = 1
//This makes reference to an existing record so the relationship can be set
nPer.person_type_id = 1;

//It says db.people because there's an option for collective nouns, it just changes the name to a 'more comprehensive one'

//Add Person to Database
db.people.Add(nPer);

//Commit
db.SaveChanges();
```

￼
I also tried assigning the Relationship itself by returning an instance of Person Type, but I get the exact same error, here what I mean:

```
postgresEntities db = new postgresEntities();
person nPer = new person();

person_type typeInstance = db.person_type.FirstOrDefault(n => n.person_type_id == 1);

nPer.person_type = typeInstance;

db.people.Add(nPer);
db.SaveChanges();
```

As you will see in the attached screenshot the variable typeInstance is in fact returning the instance of the Person Type with the ID 1 and assigning it, I thought that maybe by 'forcing' the association it will work, but it just doesn't, I get the same exact error over and over.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Model Classes (generated by Entity Framework)

```
public partial class person_type
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public person_type()
    {
        this.people = new HashSet<person>();
    }

    public int person_type_id { get; set; }
    public string person_type1 { get; set; }
    public string person_description { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<person> people { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
public partial class person
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public person()
    {
        this.addresses = new HashSet<address>();
        this.companies = new HashSet<company>();
        this.customers = new HashSet<customer>();
        this.emails = new HashSet<email>();
        this.employees = new HashSet<employee>();
        this.internal_customer = new HashSet<internal_customer>();
        this.phones = new HashSet<phone>();
    }

    public int person_id { get; set; }
    public int person_type_id { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<address> addresses { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<company> companies { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<customer> customers { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<email> emails { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<employee> employees { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<internal_customer> internal_customer { get; set; }
    public virtual person_type person_type { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<phone> phones { get; set; }
}
```

Image of FK:

[image]

Comment: Can you share `Person` and `PersonType` model classes?

Comment: it is possible you are defined a bad column relation between your tables. please share your entity classes code to provide you exact solution.

Comment: Already added them to the original post, thanks guys

Comment: I think the `person_type_id` is set to `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"`. You need to set it to "None". Basically something is wrong with your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [CodingYoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4228458/codingyoshi) I was able to work around this issue, apparently PostgreSQL generates all PKs and FKs as Serial, which by default has an auto increment declaration behind it. It doesn't mean that the model is wrong, but it seems like Entity Framework interprets it as an Auto Increment.

Setting the StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" to "None" did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you are not defining `person_type_id` as foreign key Person table.

Comment: Hafiz, I just added an screen capture of the FK, it is actually set.

Comment: do you have auto increment for foreign key ? do you have auto increment for Primary key ?